# Passing the this pointer to a constructor

Tags: oop, constructor, this, d

I'm trying to write a program in D that involves a `Server` class which creates new `Client` objects when new clients join. **I want to pass the server object to the clients when they created,** however when later I try to access the `Server` object from the client, my program stops with *error code -11*. I've googled it but found nothing.

I've successfully recreated this behavior in the following snippet:

```d
import std.stdio;



class Server
{
public:
    int n;
    Client foo() //Foo creates a new client and passes this to it
    {return new Client(this);}
}

class Client
{
public:
    this(Server sv) //Constructor takes Server object
    {sv=sv;}
    Server sv;
    void bar() //Function bar tries to access the server's n
    {writeln(sv.n);}
}

void main()
{
Server s = new Server; //Create a new server object
Client c = s.foo(); //Then ask for a client
//c.sv=s; //!!!If I leave this line in the source then it works!!!
sv.n=5; //Set it to a random value
c.bar(); //Should print 5, but instead crashes w/ error -11
}
```

If I uncomment the `c.sv=s` line, then is magically works, which I don't understand.

So why is that if I set `sv` in the constructor then it crashes, but if I set it later then it works?

**EDIT:**
Adding `writeln(sv)` to the `bar` function prints *null*, so it can cause the crash. But why is it `null`?

Comment: I am not surprised you did not see it considering your coding style...

Comment: It was a quick-n-dirty recreation of the error, done in 5 mins. The actual code is even worse. But now works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> {sv=sv;}

This line is the mistake. It sets the local `sv`, not the class instance. Try `this.sv = sv;` instead to set the instance member to the local.

edit: so since you never set the instance variable, it remains uninitialized - defaulting to null.

Comment: So I should not use the same name for the two vars?
Such a simple thing and I overlooked it... :banghead

Comment: Wel, you can use the same name, just get in the habit of using `this` with it to set thle instance variable.

Comment: If a non-null sv attribute is an invariant of your class you should add it (invariant { assert(this.sv !is null; } - it helps me a lot in situations where instance members don't get assigned due to typos or other mistakes.